# GWT RPC ClassNotFoundException while initialize AsyncCallback

Tags: gwt, callback, rpc, classnotfoundexception

this isn't my first RPC try. All others worked well, but I can't figure out, why this doesn't.

```java
    public void confirmRequest(String requestId, boolean confirmWithDefault, List<String> values, final String laneId){
    AsyncCallback<Void> callback = new AsyncCallback<Void>(){
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result)
        {
            Window.alert("jo");
            ServiceCalls.this.mainmenu.getSlidePanel().getLaneMenu().getProperLanes().get(laneId)
                    .getDefaultButton().setText("");
            statusFor();

        }

    };
    getLaneProxy().confirmRequest(requestId, confirmWithDefault, values, laneId, callback);
}
```

When I run the programm, it does not even throw an exception. It just doesn't do what it should do. Then I debugged it and saw that a ClassNotFoundException was thrown at this point.

```java
AsyncCallback< Void> callback = new AsyncCallback<Void>()
```

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: can u paste that stacktrace ?

Comment: stacktrace is null =( dunno why

Comment: If so how  you came to know its ClassNotFoundException :)  ??

Comment: debugging >.< it set a breakpoint at this line and when it stepped into, i got a classnotfoundexception

Comment: try to put breakpoint in onfailure and onsuccess and check

Comment: Trying "clean" workspace and then debug again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using GWT 2.5.0, this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7527); upgrade to 2.5.1-rc1 where this is fixed.

Comment: mhm how can am i supposed to do this? im using google plugin for eclipse

Comment: i did it now, with "check for updates". but it still doesnt work -.-

Comment: 2.5.1-rc1 still hasn't been officially announced so admittedly you couldn't know, and the Eclipse plugin bundle is always late by a few days (if not weeks; they are not made by the same people). 2.5.1-rc1 can be downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-2.5.1-rc1.zip, and is available on Central for Maven/Ivy/Gradle/etc. users

Comment: ok i changed the sdk and now i cant load my website in dev mode =/ im getting. "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:warningThreshold"

Comment: Are you depending JDT/ECJ? https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4479

Comment: gosh... now i switched back to the older version and i get the same error -.- i think i destroyed my project. and i'm not experienced enough to solve it =(

Comment: 2 things: a) read the linked issue → move GWT JARs at the top of your build path, b) as you're probably only using JDT/ECJ on the server-side, try splitting your code into 2 projects: one client-side only that depends on GWT, one server-side only that depends on ECJ/JDT and possibly gwt-servlet.jar. It won't be as simple to launch the DevMode as with a single project, but at least you're sure you won't have incompatible dependencies. Alternatively, just edit the Eclipse launcher for the DevMode and compiler and remove the server-side only dependencies from the classpath. Welcome Classpath Hell

Comment: well but where does my error finally come from? i tried it with AsyncCallback<String> and i got the same error. so it's not because of it. is it because i gave parameters to confirmRequest()? i just wanna know, because all the other rpc calls are working.

Comment: Assuming GWT 2.5.1-rc1 solved your issue, meaning you really hit issue 7527, then it would come from sending an `Arrays.asList(…)` as your `List<String>` argument (in DevMode).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem, and found the solution with [gridDragon's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614234/2355146).
My problem was that the servlet configuration in web.xml was wrong and so my Impl class couldn't be found.